# Eclipse deleted my code

Tags: java, eclipse

So I opened up Eclipse to find my entire class was comprised of one line with thousands of spaces. Am I doomed? There seems to be no local history for it.

Comment: Do you use source control of any kind? You should :)

Answer (score 2):

Try and see if eclipse kept a local copy of your recent edits.

Right click on the file -> Compare With -> Local History...

Answer (score 1):

Don't close eclipse, click on the package explorer, press CTRL + Z

It should appear again. This happened to me last week.